# Python Command Line Arguments Syntax Error

Tags: python, terminal, command-line-arguments

I am trying to print out the command line arguments, however when I try to have two print statements, I get a syntax error. Is there a reason for that?

This is my terminal input:  python3 test.py example_Resume.pdf softwareengineering

Also, how would I deal with a command-line argument that has a space in between?

```
import sys


def main(argv):
    {
    
    print(f"Name of the script      : {sys.argv[0]=}")
    print(f"Arguments of the script : {sys.argv[1:]=}") // This line errors

    }


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: Why are you passing an argument to your main function if you do not use it?

Comment: Why is code in the function  surrounded by curly braces?

Comment: That `{` starts the creation of a dict or set.  The first `print()` is valid (although not very useful) as the first element of a set.  The second `print()` is invalid because it's not separated by a comma, as required by the elements of a set.  The error has *absolutely nothing* to do with the actual content of the second print, that's just the point at which the non-Python nonsense you're writing finally got caught.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deal with command-line arguments is to use `argparse` package which takes care of shell injection, optional, default arguments.

Documentation: [Argpase](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)

Here is a sample I use for projects.

```
import argparse    


    # >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ARGUMENT PARSING <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    def args():
        """
        Used to get the list of arguments paseed to the class
        """
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    
        parser.add_argument('-r','--raw_file',type=str,
                            help='It is used to get the raw input file for parsing',
                            required=True)
 
        args = parser.parse_args()
    
        return args.raw_file

    def main():
        # PARSED RAW FILE
        raw_file=self.args()
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what the other commenters pointed out, your issue is with the curly braces.

I tried your code without them:

```
import sys


def main(argv):
    print(f"Name of the script      : {sys.argv[0]=}")
    print(f"Arguments of the script : {sys.argv[1:]=}") 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Curly braces mean something different in Python.

The question about passing the args when you don't use them in main is valid.